# Span is not aligning properly inside Div CSS

Tags: alignment, html

`<span>` is only aligning horizontally but not vertically inside `<div>`

CSS:

```
.upload-cont{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:130px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px dashed #a8a8a8;
    max-width:220px;
    max-height:180px;
    min-width:220px;
    min-height:180px;
}
.add-text{
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#999;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upload-cont">
  <span class="add-text">Something</span>
</div>
```

What should i do to align the `<span>` vertically that is at the middle of `<div>`?

**Check this jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xdYUs/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xdYUs/2/

Use `position:relative;` to the container and `position:absolute;` to the `span` element. As I've seen, your container has fixed width and height. You can use that by setting the `top` and `left` properties of the `span` element

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
.add-text{
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#999;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    margin: 40% auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xdYUs/3/)

Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

```
.add-text
{
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#999;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:170px;
}
```

line-height => 180px (container) - 10px (font size) = 170px

Comment: In actual code i had content wrapped in <span> and sentence will be breaked so each line will have 170px height.